# is the largest number $X_n$ shown up to the nth roll a Markov chain?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I'm trying to understand what is a Markov chain through *One Thousand Exercises in Probability* by Geoffrey Grimmet and David Stirzaker. I'm on exercise 6.1.2 of this book.

I know that a $X_n$ is a Markov chain if $$P(X_{n+1}=j|X_1=i_1,...,X_n=i_n)=P(X_{n+1}=j)$$

I'm trying to find out if the largest number $X_n$ shown up to the nth roll is a Markov chain?

with $Y_n$, the outcome of the nth throw, $X_{n+1}=$max{$X_n,Y_{n+1}$}, I don't understand why (solution given by the book):

$$
 p_{s,i} = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        0 & \mbox{if} \ \ \ j<i\  \\
        \frac{1}{6}i &  \mbox{if  j=i}\\
\frac{1}{6} & \mbox{if}\ j>i
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

for $1 \le i, j\le 6$
what probability is that? the one of $X_{n+1}$? How is it obtained, I understand the first line but neither the second nor the last one.

the equation above leads similarily according to the book to:

$$
 p_{s,i}(n) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        0 & \mbox{if} \ \ \ j<i\  \\
        (\frac{1}{6}i)^n &  \mbox{if  j=i}\\
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: This is when we say that a process is of Markov: $P(X_{n+1}=j|X_1=i_1,...,X_n=i_n)=P(X_{n+1}=j\mid X_n=i_n)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Markov chain in question has the following states:
$$\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$$
Let $p_{i,j}^n$ denote the probability that the chain goes to state $j$ assuming that it is in state $i$ before the $(n+1)^{th}$ roll:

$$p_{i,j}^n=P(X_{n+1}=j|X_n=i).$$

This conditional probability is $0$ if $i>j$ since the state changes only if the next roll results in a larger number than the maximum achieved so far.

$i=j$ means that the chain remains in state $i$. This event takes place if the result of the next roll is less or equal than $i$. There are $i=\#\{1,2...,i\}$ such possibilities of equal probability: $\frac16$. This is why

$$p_{i,j}^n=P(X_{n+1}=j|X_n=i)=\frac i6, \text{ if } i=j.$$

There is only one possibility of probabilty $\frac16$ to get to the state $j>i$ from state $i$, namely the result of the roll has to be exactly $j$. This is why

$$p_{i,j}^n=P(X_{n+1}=j|X_n=i)=\frac 16, \text{ if } i<j.$$

I am sorry but I don't understand what
$$
 p_{s,i}(n)
$$
is.

Comment: Thank you,  the system of equations given below was only given to understand the first one. I will try to use what you gave me to understand the whole exercise.

Comment: I actually wonder why it's not $1-\frac {i}{6}$ for $j>i$.