# Markov chain (six-sided die)

Tags: probability, markov-chains

For the following question asked by someone before, I just wonder why $\mathbb {P}\left(X_{n+1}=j\vert X_{n}=i\right)=\frac {1}{6}$ when $j>i$. I think the answer should depend on $i$, which I think the answer should be $1-\frac {i}{6}$. Thanks.

[is the largest number $X_n$ shown up to the nth roll a Markov chain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452419/is-the-largest-number-x-n-shown-up-to-the-nth-roll-a-markov-chain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for example that the largest roll after $n$ attempts is $X_n=4$

- If the next roll is any of $1,2,3,4$, so with probability $\frac46$, you get $X_{n+1}=4$ as the largest roll after $n+1$ attempts
- If the next roll is $5$, so with probability $\frac16$, you get $X_{n+1}=5$ as the largest roll after $n+1$ attempts
- If the next roll is $6$, so with probability $\frac16$, you get $X_{n+1}=6$ as the largest roll after $n+1$ attempts

and this confirms the assertion for $i=4$ and $j > i$.

You get similar results for other values of $i$.